# Python Tornado - Asynchronous Request is blocking

Tags: python, asynchronous, tornado

The request handlers are as follows:

```
class TestHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):    #  localhost:8888/test
    @tornado.web.asynchronous
    def get(self):
        t = threading.Thread(target = self.newThread)
        t.start()

    def newThread(self):
        print "new thread called, sleeping"
        time.sleep(10)
        self.write("Awake after 10 seconds!")
        self.finish()

class IndexHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):           #   localhost:8888/ 
    def get(self):
        self.write("It is not blocked!")
        self.finish()
```

When I GET `localhost:8888/test`, the page loads 10 seconds and shows `Awake after 10 seconds`; while it is loading, if I open `localhost:8888/index` in a new browser tab, the new index page is not blocked and loaded instantly. These fit my expectation.

However, while the `/test` is loading, if I open another `/test` in a new browser tab, it is blocked. The second `/test` only starts processing after the first has finished.

What mistakes have I made here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you are seeing is actually a browser limitation, not an issue with your code. I added some extra logging to your `TestHandler` to make this clear:

```
class TestHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):    #  localhost:8888/test
    @tornado.web.asynchronous
    def get(self):
        print "Thread starting %s" % time.time()
        t = threading.Thread(target = self.newThread)
        t.start()

    def newThread(self):
        print "new thread called, sleeping %s" % time.time()
        time.sleep(10)
        self.write("Awake after 10 seconds!" % time.time())
        self.finish()
```

If I open two curl sessions to localhost/test simultaneously, I get this on the server side:

```
Thread starting 1402236952.17
new thread called, sleeping 1402236952.17
Thread starting 1402236953.21
new thread called, sleeping 1402236953.21
```

And this on the client side:

```
Awake after 10 seconds! 1402236962.18
Awake after 10 seconds! 1402236963.22
```

Which is exactly what you expect. However in Chromium, I get the same behavior as you. I think that Chromium (perhaps all browsers) will only allow one connection at a time to be opened to the same URL. I confirmed this by making `IndexHandler` run the same code as `TestHandler`, except with slightly different log messages. Here's the output when opening two browser windows, one to `/test`, and one to `/index`:

```
index Thread starting 1402237590.03
index new thread called, sleeping 1402237590.03
Thread starting 1402237592.19
new thread called, sleeping 1402237592.19
```

As you can see both ran concurrently without issue.

Comment: I can't believe this is the browser's problem.... I took me a whole day trying to figure out what happened!! Thanks so much!

Comment: This was driving me crazy for an hour now.

Answer (score 0):

I think you picked the "wrong" test for checking parallel `GET` requests, that's because you're using a *blocking* function for your test: `time.sleep()`, which its behavior doesn't really occur when you simply render an HTML page ...

What happens is, that the `def get()` ( which handle all GET requests ) is actually being blocked when you use `time.sleep` it cannot process any new GET requests, puts them in some kind of "queue".

So if you really want to test `sleep()` - use the Tornado *non-blocking* function: `tornado.gen.sleep()`

Example:

```
from tornado import gen

@gen.coroutine
def get(self):        
    yield self.time_wait()       

@gen.coroutine
def time_wait(self):
    yield gen.sleep(15)
    self.write("done")
```

Open multiple tabs in your browser, then you'll see that all requests are being processed when they arrive w/o "queueing" the new requests that comes in ..

Comment: While it is true that `thread.sleep()` is normally bad to use in a non-blocking application, because the `sleep` call is farmed off to a background thread in this case, it doesn't block the second `get()` call. This is proven by the fact that sending concurrent requests with curl works normally. The problem is with the web browser serializing the requests to the same url.

Comment: what do you mean ? the client still wait for the request ( because of the `yield` ) - but at least it's not blocking the server from processing other requests ... that's what I was trying to say ..

Comment: The `time.sleep()` call in the question doesn't block the server from processing other requests, because it's done in a background thread, not on the tornado ioloop thread.

Comment: in a single-thread Tornado server it does. I've tested it. my users were "queued" and only when the `time.sleep` finished, the 2nd user got processed the `get` request. `time.sleep` is not in a background thread -> but if you'll use `tornado.gen.sleep` - then you'd be right

Comment: In the original question, the call to `time.sleep()` is explicitly made in a background thread. Note the `t = threading.Thread(target = self.newThread)` call in the `get` method. Take a look at my answer - the OPs code that uses `time.sleep()` does not block the second call if you use `curl`, or make the second call from a different browser. You are right that in general using `time.sleep()` is not the right thing to do in a non-blocking application, but it is not the problem the OP was having in this case. He would have had the same issue with `tornado.gen.sleep`.

Comment: ohhh yes yes yes, I just wanted to write a comment about this topic, that people will know they don't have to use Threads ... they can use Tornado's alternatives