# Tornado AsyncHTTPClient behavior on slow requests

Tags: asynchronous, tornado

Given this basic example:

```
import tornado.gen
import tornado.httpclient
import tornado.web
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web


class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    @tornado.web.asynchronous
    @tornado.gen.engine
    def get(self):
        client = tornado.httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient()
        response = yield tornado.gen.Task(client.fetch, 'http://slowserver-with-a-fake-5s-sleep')
        self.write(str(response.code))
        self.finish()


application = tornado.web.Application([
    (r"/", MainHandler),
])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.listen(9999)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

When I hit '/' twice I can see my artificially slow server receiving two requests responses with 5s in between.

Shouldn't tornado fire two requests one after an other and wait for the responses? Why is the ioloop blocked?

## tornado 2.4

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python Tornado - Asynchronous Request is blocking](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24106503/python-tornado-asynchronous-request-is-blocking)

Answer (score 0):

Ouch yes and the answer is interesting. It is just Chrome queueing the requests to the same url...