# Why tornado doesn't go concurrently?

Tags: python, asynchronous, tornado

The following is my test code. I am using Python2.7, with `futures` installed using:

```
pip install futures
```

The following is my demo code:

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
from tornado.gen import coroutine, Task
from tornado.concurrent import Future
import time


class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    @coroutine
    def get(self):
        print "in"
        res = yield Task(self._work)
        self.write(res)

    def _work(self, callback):
        time.sleep(10)
        callback("hello world!")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application = tornado.web.Application([
        (r"/", MainHandler),
    ])
    application.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

This code should go concurrently, shouldn't it? However, it just doesn't.

I tested with Firefox and IE. I think I made some mistakes. It would be nice for you to point out my error.

only one request at a time(`http://localhost:8888/`:

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
from tornado.gen import coroutine, Return, Task
from tornado.process import Subprocess
from tornado.concurrent import Future
from threading import Thread
import time

@coroutine
def async_sleep(timeout):
    """ Sleep without blocking the IOLoop. """
    yield Task(tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().add_timeout, time.time() + timeout)

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    @coroutine
    def get(self):
        print "in"
        res = yield self._work()
        self.write(res)

    @coroutine
    def _work(self):
        yield async_sleep(5)
        raise Return("hello world!")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application = tornado.web.Application([
        (r"/", MainHandler),
    ])
    application.listen(8888)
    ioloop=tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance()
    Thread(target=ioloop.start).start()
```

Comment: You can't use `time.sleep`, because that will block tornado's I/O loop. You need to use a non-blocking method to sleep, instead. See the duped question for an example.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does long-polling work in Tornado?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16428231/how-does-long-polling-work-in-tornado)

Comment: @dano `sleep` here is the true problem i think. in practice, i am going to call a bash command, which may take such time period. any good advice?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you indicated in the comments you want to run a subprocess via tornado, here's an example illustrating how to do that. I also fixed a logic error where you were creating a `Task` when calling `_work`, which wasn't going to work the way you intended:

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
from tornado.gen import coroutine, Return
from tornado.process import Subprocess
from tornado.concurrent import Future

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    @coroutine
    def get(self):
        print "in"
        res = yield self._work()
        self.write(res)

    @coroutine
    def _work(self):
        p = Subprocess(['sleep', '10'])
        f = Future()
        p.set_exit_callback(f.set_result)
        yield f
        raise Return("hello world!")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application = tornado.web.Application([
        (r"/", MainHandler),
    ])
    application.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

As you can see, I made `_work` a coroutine, and then used [tornado's built-in `Subprocess`](http://tornado.readthedocs.org/en/latest/process.html#tornado.process.Subprocess) class to execute a command. I created a `Future` object, and instructed the `Subprocess` to call `Future.set_result(return_code_of_subprocess)` when it completed. Then I called `yield` on the `Future` instance. That  makes the code wait until the subprocess completes, without blocking the I/O loop.

Comment: that looks good. but i noticed a problem. i started two requests and the second one couldn't be handled before the first one returns. could you show me a way to make the handler unblocked? for convenience, i reference to the dup and use `async_sleep` to simulate. please see update.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr Are you testing this from a web browser? If so, you're probably hitting the issue I describe [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24107123/2073595). Basically, you're seeing a browser limitation. If you were to test this using two browsers simultaneously or via curl, it will work fine.

Comment: I was wondering if the command is not `['sleep', '10']` but `['ls', '-l']`, how may I return the result of `ls -l` to `get(self)`?

Answer (score 0):

The `time.sleep` in your code is a blocking method.
You need `tornado.gen.sleep`(a non-blocking method, new in tornado 4.1) here to instead.