# why tornado asynchronous doesn't work

Tags: python, asynchronous, tornado

Today, when I want to make some Synchronous Python Library to functioning asynchronously, but it doesn't work. After a series of testing, I found that even the `yield tornado.gen.sleep(N)` functioning synchronously.

Here's my code:

```
import time
import tornado.web
import tornado.gen
import tornado.ioloop
import os


class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.render("test.htm")


class SleepHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        time.sleep(2)
        self.write("Good morning!")


class YSleepHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    @tornado.gen.coroutine
    def get(self):
        yield tornado.gen.sleep(2)
        self.write("Good morning!")


def main():
    app = tornado.web.Application([
        (r"/sleep", SleepHandler),
        (r"/ysleep", YSleepHandler),
        (r"/", MainHandler),
        ], debug=True, template_path=os.path.split(
            os.path.realpath(__file__))[0])
    app.listen(8888)
    try:
        tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
    except:
        tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().stop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I use the code below to test out the asynchronous function works or not(in test.htm -- template file for MainHandler):

```
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
                $.get("/sleep");
            }
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
                $.get("/ysleep");
            }
```

But finally, I got an unexpected [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0f2A.jpg).

What's the matter? I tried under both Python2.7 and Python3.4 environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, this problem has been resloved by adding some unique useless arguments to the end of the URL.

```
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
                $.get("/sleep");
            }
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
                $.get("/ysleep");
            }
```

If you use the code above to test out the result, you will receive the same result like you're using synchronous code(Because tornado will return 304 not modified, it's a synchronous function.). but if use the use the code below, the differences between synchronous and asynchronous will be illustrated totally.

```
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
                $.get("/sleep", {"random": Math.random()});
            }
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
                $.get("/ysleep", {"random": Math.random()});
            }
```

Comment: It's a limitation of some browsers that they will not open more than one connection to the same URL. So with the first code example the browser is actually performing the blocking.

Comment: Yep, @AntBlackshaw is right. See [this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24106503/python-tornado-asynchronous-request-is-blocking)

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing this behaviour because *yield* in a coroutine effectively transfers control back to Tornado's IOLoop. It does not means that it returns a result to the client - merely that it returns control to Tornado so that the IOLoop won't be blocked by a long running request.

The effect that this has on your code is that Tornado will block while SleepHandler runs whereas it will not block when YSleepHandler runs. In both cases the response will be returned to the client only when your handler calls *self.write()*, but in the case of YSleepHandler, other requests can be serviced when the handler is running because the IOLoop is not blocked.

Comment: In fact, I tested out the two handler's result separately, SleepHandler was not called When I was testing YSleepHandler. But, finally I got the [result](http://i.stack.imgur.com/s0f2A.jpg). Could you tell me how to rewrite this code in the right way?